# Updating ViewChild for clr-datagrid in clr-wizard

Tags: angular, datagrid, vmware-clarity

First time posting here and hoping for some advise (unable to find anything to confirm this has been done before).

Currently, I have clr-wizard which allows the end-user to navigate and select options for VM restore operations. On the final page, I have a clr-wizard-page which contains the following:

```
  <ng-template clrPageTitle>Export Options</ng-template>
    You have selected to recover <b>{{selectedVM[0].vm_name}}</b>. Please select your recovery options:
    <div class="form-group">   
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="rad1" (click)= "changeValue(false,'noMapping')"> No Mapping
        <input type="radio" name="rad1" (click)= "changeValue(false,'deleteNics')"> Deleted NICs of all VMs
        <input type="radio" name="rad1" (click)= "changeValue(true, 'advanced')"> Advanced
      </div>
      <ng-container *ngIf="isValid; then exportadvanced;"></ng-container>
        <ng-template #exportadvanced>
          <clr-datagrid class="datagrid-compact" #datagridExportAdvanced >
            <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'rVM'">
              VM Name
            </clr-dg-column>
            <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'rVMNicIndex'">
              NIC Index
            </clr-dg-column>
            <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'rVMNetwork'">
              Network
            </clr-dg-column>
            <clr-dg-row *ngFor="let rvOption of this.rvOptionsVms">
              <clr-dg-cell>{{rvOption.name}}</clr-dg-cell>
              <clr-dg-cell>{{rvOption.nicIndex}}</clr-dg-cell>
              <clr-dg-cell>                              
                <select [(ngModel)]="vmnetwork">
                  <option *ngFor="let vmnetwork of this.rvOptionsNetworks" [value]="vmnetwork.name" [selected]="vmnetwork.name">
                  {{vmnetwork.name}}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </clr-dg-cell>
              </clr-dg-row>         
              <clr-dg-footer>
                {{paginationRec.firstItem + 1}} - {{paginationRec.lastItem + 1}} of {{paginationRec.totalItems}} VMs
               <clr-dg-pagination #paginationRec [clrDgPageSize]="10"></clr-dg-pagination>
              </clr-dg-footer>                 
            </clr-datagrid>
          </ng-template>      
          </div>
        </clr-wizard-page>
```

The difficult comes on submit and accessing data from the datagrid; in my typescript I have the following:

```
export class ObjectComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild("datagridExportAdvanced") dgExportAdvanced: Datagrid;

    public exportOnSubmit(){

      console.log('Debug: Logging DG',this.datagridExportAdvanced);
      console.log(`Debug: Show DG Rows ${this.datagridExportAdvanced.rows}`);

    }
}
```

The Datagrid returns the console log fine and I can see from items and rows that there is data there, but the column refs and items refs all show as undefined even though the array size is valid e.g. 3 items and displayName value shows undefined for each item in the array.

I suspect this is due to the Datagrid being populated during the wizard and also having an onLoad function to populate the select boxes. I have attempted to use console.log to trigger an update of the ViewChild but the outputs remain undefined.

Ideally I just need to be able to read the contents of the Datagrid and store it, so I can add it to an API POST payload.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, you already have the list of items in your controller so why do you need to parse the contents of the rows? Also, do you need a datagrid for this or can a table satisfy your needs?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the data is in the controller, but when I query the rows, the array counts display the correct amount of objects (e.g. array(5)), but when I return the values, I get undefined for every item (column names are undefined and items are undefined). It's almost as if the viewchild needs refreshed post data population (not 100% sure if thats possible from clr-wizard). On a side note, I've tested tables and I can get the data I need so I'll run with this for now and come back to datagrids if I need pagination or filtering.

Comment: You should not try to inspect the contents of the DOM to manage your data models. I still don't really understand why you are trying to get the DOM data when you have datagrid input bindings to know what page of records are being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a known issue with clarity.
If you want to use a Datagrid in a Modal or a Wizard page the Datagrid is rendered not correct and the height = 0px.

[Here is the issue with a workaround](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2364)

Just set `height: auto !important` to the Datagrid style and it is rendered correct.